# Why is there no emplace or emplace_back for std::string?

Tags: c++, string, emplace

I'm pretty sure I've seen this asked on here before, but I can't seem to find the post when I tried searching, and I don't recall the answer.

Why is there no `emplace` or `emplace_back` for `std::string`?

I don't think it's related to the use of `char`, since you can have a vector of chars, and there's no problem with `emplace_back`ing a char in the vector.

Comment: Some food for thought: `std::basic_string<T>` can be used a generic container with some handy advantages over `std::vector<T>`. See this CppCon talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDJImePyftY

Comment: Writing and submitting a standards proposal for `std::basic_string` (and friends) to grow `emplace()`/`emplace_back()` is always an option.

Comment: @alterigel The standard seems to allow only non-array POD types for `std::basic_string`, so the use as generic container is quite limited, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/strings#general-1 (and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/strings#basic.string-1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There would be no gain over `push_back`

The power of `emplace_back` is that it **constructs an object in-place**, where it is designed to stay. No copies or moves are needed. And it also provides simpler syntax for creating objects, but that's just a minor advantage.

```
class Person
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    double salary;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> people;
    people.push_back(Person{"Smith", 42, 10000.0}); //temporary object is needed, which is moved to storage
    people.emplace_back("Smith", 42, 10000.0); //no temporary object and concise syntax
}
```

For `std::string` (or any theoretical container that can only hold primitive types), the gain is nonexistent. No matter if you construct object in place or move it or copy it, you perform the same operation at assembly level - write some bytes at given memory.
Syntax also cannot become more concise than it is - there is no constructor that needs to be called. You can use a literal or another variable, but you have to do exactly same thing in both `push_back` and `emplace_back`

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<char> letters;
    letters.push_back('a');
    letters.emplace_back('a'); //no difference
}
```

Comment: _"can only hold primiteve types"_ I don't think the standard forbids non-primitive types. cppreference says it has to be a trivial type, but [this](https://godbolt.org/z/DdSV_x) still compiles so I'm not sure what to think of this. I couldn't find a constraint in the standard other than _"char-like object"_ which isn't actually defined afaik.

Comment: It would still be nice for homogeneity. If you have a function template that works with containers generically, you either can't use `emplace_back` or you can't support `std::string`.

Comment: `std::basic_string`, being a template, doesn't have to use `char`.

Comment: Consider `std::basic_string<Person>`

Comment: @RichardCritten That presumes you have some sort of `char_traits<Person>`.

Comment: @François I think the needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few, here. When we add `emplace_back` for strings, many people would start to use it for imaginary gains and this would introduce confusion and ambiguity. For those few with the need for uniform container syntax, it would 1) not be hard to write a function emplaces if possible and push_backs if necessary and 2) this would probably already be necessary since `set` has `emplace` and not `emplace_back`.

Comment: "There would be no gain over push_back" what is the gain `std::array::max_size()` over `std::array::size()`?

Comment: @n314159 actually according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string since C++17 `std::string` must satisfy SequenceContainer concept which requires `emplace_back` to exist so this looks like a defect to me

Comment: @n314159 There is already a solution to uniform insertion which is the `insert` member which all containers have (even maps and sets). And I don't agree that adding `emplace` members would lead to confusion. Maybe the performance gains are imaginary, but that's no different from any other container's `emplace_back` with certain types. There already exists a ton of `std::vector<int>::emplace_back()` calls in countless projects and it causes no harm at all. While it's true that there isn't much to gain and it isn't free to add, introducing confusion is not a real cost in this case.

Comment: @Slava It seems to me that the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string) only requires string to be a contiguous container which in turn only adds requirements to its iterators not its interface.

Comment: @François I see your point, but I think, that often enough one would ask oneself "Why was emplace_back used here and not push_back?" as it is already the case for `vector`, when emplace is used willy-nilly. Of course there are arguments for both directions and I wouldn't complain if there were an `emplace_back` for string, but I also don't complain about its absence.

Comment: @Slava [SequenceContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer) only requires `emplace_back` for `deque`, `list` and `vector`. I think this is rather a defect in cppreference's wording

Comment: @Timo As n31419 pointed out `basic_string` is not a sequence container. cppreference says it is but that isn't supported by the standard. Edit : It looks like this might be a recent change. Edit 2 : Not it's not.

Comment: Wouldn't an advantage be in templating? Say you have a templated function. Inside the function, there is a templated variable that can be `std::string` or `std::vector`, and you need to do some appending to the variable . For conformity, if they both had `emplace_back`, then you could operate as follows: `var.emplace_back(something)`, but since `std::string` doesn't have this functionality, this would only work if `var` was a `std::vector`.

Edit: I just saw @François Andrieux comment above. I think his is identical to what I'm saying here.

Comment: `std::basic_string<std::string>>` ... ow, I've hurt my brain.

Comment: @Timo "*char-like*" is defined in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/strings#general-1 to mean non-array POD, i.e. trivial and standard-layout. I think your example has undefined behavior.

Comment: Really good explanation. This is what I thought too before I saw your answer. Thank you!
As a side note the primitive type are move-assignable/ constructible however there's no benefit of moving them.

Comment: I wish I had std::string::emplace for that kind of things: "key.emplace(data, data + length);" to avoid for instance: "key = std::string(data, data + length);".

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of (e.g.) `std::vector‹T>::emplace_back` is that it constructs an object of type T directly in the vector, instead of constructing a temporary and then copying it in.

Since `char` is a primitive type, there is no advantage in one method over the other, so there is no reason for `std::string::emplace_back` to exist.

Comment: There is a big reason for `std::string::emplace_back` to exist - common interface for generic programming